# js regexp - to escape character, needs one backward slash? or two?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't understand when I need one and two backward slashes `\`.

First, see an example:

```
const rxHttps = new RegExp("\/");
console.log(rxHttps.test("/")); // true

const rxQuestion = new RegExp("\\?");
console.log(rxQuestion.test("?")); // true

const rxAnotherQuestion = new RegExp("\?"); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to repeat
```

In the above example, **to use a character `/`, it needs just one `\`.**

However, **`?` needs two `\`, or SyntaxError occurs.**

This is really confusing. I can't make heads or tails of it.

Why are they different? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You do not escape `/` in `RegExp("\/")`, it is equal to `RegExp("/")`, and it is OK as `/`  is not a special regex metacharacter.

Comment: You can go with this tutorial https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah... I totally misunderstood. Thank you very much

Comment: Also, you can go with this https://sites.hks.harvard.edu/research/Macromedia/HomeSite+/Help/Using_HomeSite+_for_Dreamweaver_MX/language5.html

Answer (score 0):

because '?' is used to mean that what's before it can or not exist like {0,}

for example

```
var reg = new RegExp('a?');
// this has the same meaning as using
// var reg = new RegExp('a\?');
reg.test('a'); // will display true
reg.test('anything'); // this will also display true
reg.test('123'); // this also displays true
```

so if you want to check of the existence of '?' character, you have to escape it, and since it's used as '\?' also, then you have to escape it using '\?'

Why does it give you syntax error ?
because it's expecting something to check if it exists or not and you're not giving it anything.